# how to download some java jar library files

Tags: java, android

Has anyone migrated a an application using Java AWT library to run on Android?  How do you do this?  I am using these packages.

```
 java.awt.AWTException;
 java.awt.Robot;
 java.awt.Rectangle;
 java.awt.Toolkit;
 java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 java.io.*;
 javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Comment: Here's a start: http://tinyurl.com/2dp6kds ;-)

Comment: i googled a lot i got some links to download but did not get for free download..can you give me a link,if you know..

Comment: hi jyoseph thanks for your interest.. you given the link that only explains about the classes but i need to download those libraries in .jar format...

Comment: possible duplicate of [android api for java.awt.Robot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416228/android-api-for-java-awt-robot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the AWT jar here: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!jar+awt

rt.jar (in your JDK setup) has java.awt package. It has all the core java packages.

Try this in android: http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/

Comment: actually i need separate jar files for each libraries...because i have written a java code and i want to run that code in my android project by including those libraries manually.

Answer (score 1):

all those classes are part of the standard JDK. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

What kind and version of Java are you using?

Comment: i am using jdk 6.0 version...actually i need separate jar files for each libraries...because i have written a java code and i want to run that code in my android project by including those libraries manually...

Comment: The fact you want to run this on andriod is worth mentioning given that you cannot just take a AWT library for Java and expect it to work on Android. It has to be an AWT library for android.