# Android API like java.awt.Robot

Tags: java, android

Is there an Android API analogous to java.awt.Robot, i.e. an API allowing to take screenshots?

Comment: You need to ask 1 question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416059/how-to-download-some-java-jar-library-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java.awt.Robot is not available in the Android SDK.

If you want to make screenshots by your own during development you can use DDMS. If your application should make screenshots, I think this requires root. There are application that can do that, e.g.

http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Others/Screenshot-Android-71410.shtml

There is also a library available that may be useful for you:

[Android Screenshot Library (ASL)](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/)

However, there is also a disucssion on SO:

[How to capture the android device screen content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content)

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to simulate **touch events** (just like robot does with mouse clicks) use the utility class [`TouchUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Robot` class is only available in Java, this is not supported in Android, Too see what are the classes supported in Android, pls click [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Comment: then how can i write a program in android that takes screenshot.

Comment: what's the alternative of Robot in android? I want to make some  clicking functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

class TouchUtils...
This class was deprecated in API level 24.
Use Espresso UI testing framework instead. New tests should be written using the Android Testing Support Library.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator