# Robot class like classes for android

Tags: java, android, class, awtrobot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android API like java.awt.Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416228/android-api-like-java-awt-robot)

Are there any other classes for android like Robot class in java, OR can we use Robot class in android ?

Answer (score 6):

No, but an equivalent for you could be [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) on Android.

For instance with `sendKeyDownUpSync(int key)` for sending an up and down key event sync to the currently focused window.

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
```

There is also the utility class [`TouchUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) to simulate touch events. Although I have to note, that the Instrumentation class is actually only [used for testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation), so it depends on what you want to achieve anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for testing you can look up Robotium, http://code.google.com/p/robotium/. It's Selenium for Android.