# Running java program from phone

Tags: java, android, bots

I am currently making a simple bot using the Java Robot Class and what this bot does is click on a certain program's icon from the taskbar (It's a download manager) and then press the pause/play button. I was wondering if there were some way to run this program from my android phone without having to go up to the desktop PC and run it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit to clarify why this isn't a duplicate: I am not asking how to simulate something like the robot class on android, but how to run a java program on pc using an android phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robot class like classes for android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580465/robot-class-like-classes-for-android)

Comment: Hello Lal, I was not asking how to simulate something like the robot class on android, but how to run a java program on pc using an android phone. Edit added for clarification.